# Is it advisable to have Parse and App Engine directly communicate to each other

Tags: android, rest, google-app-engine, parse-platform

This question probably betrays my low computer science aptitude, but please bear with me and help if you can.

I have some codes running on App Engine (REST API), and I have some Cloud Code running on Parse. Here is the question: is it advisable to have the Parse Cloud Code call a function on App Engine? So basically the user would make a call to Parse, then Parse would contact App Engine and then use the response from App Engine to decide which data to return to user: `Android Client -> Parse Cloud Code -> App Engine REST api -> Parse Cloud Code -> Android Client`. The reason I don’ do `Android Client -> App Engine -> Android Client; and then Android Client -> Parse -> Android Client` is to save the user bandwidth, time (slow network), and money. Thanks for helping.

P.S. The app engine code would be an endpoint and the parse code would be cloud code (i.e. both REST apis).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it as far as I can tell. What makes you doubt whether it is advisable?

Comment: I am not the most experienced in the bunch so I figure someone out here may know better.